# Conversion from 32 bit binary string to int Java

Tags: java, bit

Why does this code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //                           |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |    
    int N = (int)Long.parseLong("10110011001100111111001111111100", 2);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(N)); 
    N = Integer.parseInt       ("-0110011001100111111001111111100", 2);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(N)); 
    N = Integer.parseInt       ("+0110011001100111111001111111100", 2); 
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(N));
}
```

Outputs:

```
10110011001100111111001111111100
11001100110011000000110000000100
110011001100111111001111111100
```

Javadocs: "The '-' sign can be specified to indicate negative values". Why are the first two binary strings different?

Comment: Well, that's how two's complement works

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: They are different because they represent different values. Please edit your question for clarity: it's not at all obvious what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: The - sign specified in parseInt() method doesn't just push a 1 bit at 32nd bit position, it converts the number represented by the string to have a negative value using two's complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how the two's complement works. To negate a number it is inverting all the bits and adding 1 to the result.

Example:
         *negating*
11110001 ----------> 00001111